# I want to show a window modal without any error after hide if it´s success

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-4

I´ve my controller

```
  public function postCreate()
    {
        //validamos reglas inputs
        $rules = array(
          'inputuser' => 'required|max:10',
          'inputpassword' => 'required|min:8',
          'inputpassword1' => 'required|min:8',
          'inputemail' => 'required|email|unique:users,email'
        );

        $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
        //Si no pasa la validacion
        if($validation->fails())
        {
            //Obtenemos los mensajes de error de la validation
            $messages = $validation->messages();
            //Redireccionamos a nuestro formulario de atras con los errores de la validación 
            if(Request::ajax())
            {
                return Response::json(array('errors' => $messages));
            }
            else
            {
                return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validation);
            }
        }
        //Si todo ha ido bien guardamos
        $password = Input::get('inputpassword');
        $user = new User;
        $user->username = Input::get('inputuser');
        $user->password = Hash::make($password);
        $user->email = Input::get('inputemail'); 
        $user->admin = (Input::get('es_admin') == '1') ? 1 : 0;

        //guardamos
        $user->save();

        //redirigimos a usuarios

        return Redirect::to('admin/users.index')->with('status','ok_create');

    }
```

My main.js in ajax

```
$("document").ready(function()
{
   $("#formuser-create").submit(function()
   {
      event.preventDefault();
      var form = $(this);
      $.ajax({
         url: 'users/create',
         dataType:'json',
         data: form.serialize(),
         type: "POST", 
         success: function(response)
         {
             if(response.success)
             {
                 $("#box-modal").modal('hide');
             }
             else(response.error)
             {
                $.each(response.errors, function( index, value ) {
                $("input[name='"+index+"']" ).css('border: 2px solid #FF0000;');
                $("input[name='"+index+"']" ).parent().append(value[0]);
                });
             }
         },
         error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError)
         {
             console.log(xhr.status);
             console.log(thrownError);
             console.log(textStatus);
         }
      });
   }); 
});
```

I want to redirect to admin/user and load the view index.blade, with a message of that´s "ok_create" if it´s sucess. But don´t hide the window modal. 
I think that don´t hide the modal window in the ajax, because I redirect in my controller when it´s correct.

will I have to make all the code in ajax? , with window.location.href and send a value ok_correct

I´m confused, anyone could help me, with an example?

Answer (score 0):

If you redirect to another page then only option is to open the modal again as it will be totally new page load. You can use @if statements with some boolean flags.

In this scenario you can redirect the user to another URL and include param that controller will set again in the view. In the view you can trigger the modal programmatically after page load event.

If you want the modal to stay open and view behind modal to change then you need to make dynamic ajax website. It is relatively complex and I do not believe this is worth it.

Comment: I need an example. I´m lost. When the data been correct, I have than close modal in ajax and redirect an page with a status